# Как инициализировать объект

Tags: vb.net

Я создал класс.
Файл `Cars` (класс):

```
Public model As String
Public number As String

Public Sub add()
     model = Form2.Text1.Text
     number = Form2.Text1.Text
End Sub
```

Файл `Form2` (код с нажатия кнопки):

```
Dim a As New Cars
a.add
```

Выбивает ошибку. Ошибку не помню, пишу с телефона код. Как её исправить?

Comment: вам все-таки стоит вспомнить ошибку. потому что если Cars - класс, то все должно работать.

Comment: Так правильно вообще так забивать объект данными или проще делать присваивание в самой кнопке после создания объекта?  Например a. model = ...

Comment: правильнее - передавать "параметры" объекта в его конструктор

Comment: кстати, код в вопросе полностью рабочий. даже не знаю как его можно исправить.

Answer (score 1):

Я точно не знаю как это на VB (я работаю на С#). Но попробуйте так

```
Public Sub add(_form as Form)
model = _form.Text1.Text
number = _form.Text1.Text
End Sub



Dim a As New Cars
a.add(Form2)
```

Comment: В VB.NET есть глобальная коллекция My.Application.Forms, через которую он и пытается обратиться к форме. Но это действительно плохой вариант, твой лучше. Только `add(Form2)`.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Не знал, что в VB.NET можно глобально обращаться к формам.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Car
  Public Property Model As String
  Public Property Number As String

  Public Sub New(Model As String, Number As String)
    With Me
      .Model = Model
      .Number = Number
    End With
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: А когда данные передавать в конструктор? При объявлении или после? Если можно,  то покажите как лучше.

Comment: @TemaGr, если форма нужна именно для редактирования или создания элемента, я бы во-первых, сделал это содержимое UserControl'ом, а во-вторых, добавил бы ему свойство Value, полями которого он будет манипулировать. Аналогично можно поступить и с формой. Т. е. форма сама предоставляет сформированный объект вызывающему коду по аналогии с тем, как диалог выбора файла/папки предоставляет имя.